# Why does typeof 3>2 return false in javascript console?

Tags: javascript, typeof

The following link provides a description and examples about how typeof works:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Couldn't find an explanation of what? Please put the question in the body of your post, the title should indicate the topic you're asking about.

Answer (score 5):

Because `typeof 3` is not more than `2`.

You need parentheses.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the result is false.

Answer (score 3):

To explain what's going on, the interpreter treats it as:

```
(typeof 3) > 2
```

The *typeof* operator always returns a string, and `3` is a number so the expression resolves to:

```
'number' > 2
```

The [*Greater-than Operator ( > )*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.2) applies the [*Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) to get the result of the comparison. Since 'number' is a String, it's converted to a Number using the internal [*ToNumber*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) operation (step 3a). A string that doesn't contain a number literal (e.g. "3") results in *NaN* (see note below), so now the expression is:

```
NaN > 2
```

Step 3c says if the left hand expression is *NaN*, return *undefined* (that is, the special [*undefined* value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.9), not the string 'undefined').

So *undefined* is returned, and step 6 of the *greater–than operator* algorithm says:

> If [the result] is undefined, return false. Otherwise, return [the result].

so ultimately, the expression returns *false*.

**Note**: a string containing only whitespace (one or more spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.) converts to the number `0`, which is the only case where a string that isn't a numeric literal converts to a number value other than NaN. See [*ToNumber Applied to the String Type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3.1).

Comment: "How does undefined get converted to false?"  Very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript the operator "typeof" has a precedence of 4 while the operator greater ">" than has a precedence of 8, so according to the example mentioned in the question typeof 3 gets evaluated first and then compared to 2 which returns false.

More details can be found about precedence and associativity of operators at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence